# What is a "top cap" on a climber's haul bag?

Tags: gear, rock-climbing

What is a "top cap" on a climber's haul bag and how does it work? In *Mountaineering: The Freedom of the Hills* (and also at [neilhopkins.us/mountaineering-guide-2/aid-climbing-equipment](http://www.neilhopkins.us/mountaineering-guide-2/aid-climbing-equipment.html)) is

> A top cap to the haul bag is a good idea to protect the knot connecting the sack to the haul line and help reduce snagging problems while hauling.

but there is no diagram. I can imagine what it looks like because of

> An effective top cap can be readily fashioned from an empty 2-liter plastic bottle.

Is the sequence like this, from bottom going up: haul sac, strap, carabiner, knot, (upright) "top cap", then haul rope, with the rope going through the small opening of the bottle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's exactly what it is, a *top cap* or *knot protector* is simply there to help protect your knot on the swivel from getting abraded against the rock while you're up-hauling:

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://www.climbing.com/news/your-first-big-wall/)</sup>
[image]
<sup>[Source](https://hikinginfinland.com/2015/06/arcteryx-alpine-academy-chamonix-2015.html)</sup>